# VBA se selcionar celula, preencher

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Boa noite, Estou preparando uma planilha de registro VBA e gostaria que, ao selecionar uma célula específica, ela fosse preenchida com um X e excluísse as outras alternativas possíveis ...

Se possível, gostaria de excluir algumas linhas se a seleção for feita

Tentei a seguinte fórmula, mas sem sucesso:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = True

If Range(“U23”).Select Then
Range(“U23”) = "(X)"
Range(“Z23”) = "( )"
Range(“AE23”) = "( )"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Se precisa ser na seleção, você precisa alterar de:

Private Sub Worksheet_**Change**(ByVal Target As Range) para
Private Sub Worksheet_**SelectionChange**(ByVal Target As Range)

E provavelmente, o código abaixo te atenda melhor:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

Rows(Target.row).clear
Target.value = "(X)"

Application.EnableEvents = true

End Sub
```